# Coredata not supporting in predicate but only on non-home compute

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm following the example from apple about importing data efficiently (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html)

My code example look like this

```
NSString* predicateString = @" IN %@)";
predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@%@", predicatePrefix, predicateString];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString, sortedServerIDs]];

// make sure the results are sorted as well
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                   [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: predicatePrefix
                                                               ascending:YES]]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *matchingManagedObjects = [__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

---

The resulting error is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (businessesID IN {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 39})'
```

However this works on my home computer in the simulator, and it works on my device!
I'm running xcode 4.2.1 on both machines.

I tried following this answer: 
[Does CoreData on iPhone support IN predicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436032/does-coredata-on-iphone-support-in-predicates)

But received the same error

If it matters when I check my SQLite version on my machine I have:

sqlite3 --version
3.7.8 2011-09-19 14:49:19 3e0da808d2f5b4d12046e05980ca04578f581177

Answer (score 0):

You need to use %K in your format string when you're referencing a field name

```
NSString* predicateString = @" IN %@)";
predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%K%@", predicatePrefix, predicateString];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString, sortedServerIDs]];

// make sure the results are sorted as well
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                               [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: predicatePrefix
                                                           ascending:YES]]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *matchingManagedObjects = [__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Unfortunately still receive the same error verbatim using: `[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", predicatePrefix, sortedServerIDs]];` ----------- error --------- `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (businessesID IN {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 39})'`

Comment: I can also compile form this machine to the phone, and it works. Just not in the simulator

Comment: Could this be an issue with the simulator, or sqlite version on this machine?